# How do probabilities work in C#

Tags: c#

I asked this question earlier but worded it all wrong so trying to make it more clear.

So to put it into context I'm currently training to be a software developer and I've been struggling to understand the concept of probabilities in C#, I'm completely new to C# and found that this was one of the best sites I could find to get support when learning how to develop new coding languages.

I'm trying to create a program that acts as a random number generator using numbers -1 to 3 and setting an individual probability for each of the numbers.

I've fully created my code which will randomnly print 4 numbers in the range of -1 to 3 but I'm currently struggling to understand exactly how to implement probability functions to each number individually.

Here is my current code that works as a random number generator to pull the numbers with an equal chance:

```
while (again)
{
    List<int> scores = new List<int>();

    Random generator = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int score = generator.Next(-1, 4);

        Console.WriteLine(score);

        scores.Add(score);
    }

    ConsoleKeyInfo keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();

    Console.Clear();

    if (keyPressed.Key != ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

The probabilities I need to set the the numbers are:
[0.01, 0.3, 0.58, 0.1, 0.01]
to the numbers
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3]

Initially I thought to use a new randomnumber class to each section in order to define them as a probability but was unsure how to use probabilities in C#.

I know I posted this earlier but I didnt word it as well as I should of and was asking for things such as the best way or the most efficient way which was taken negatively when all I really need to know is how probabilities can actually be created in C#.

Help would be greatly appreciated as all the ways I've tried to implement it haven't worked and other solutions I've found online I'm unsure how to extract pieces of other code which actually apply a probabilities function, I know there is other code which gives the entire solution but I want to be able to implement a piece of code into my own solution that will work so that I can get a better understanding on how this function works.

Help with this would be greatly appreciated and I apologise if posting a similar post two times in one day is annoying to users but I'm genuinely hitting a brick wall when it comes to trying to understand how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is an example of code that I've tried to implement into my code as suggested in the comments, based off of this code I found online from here:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/making-random-range-generate-a-value-with-probability.336374/

```
    {
        while (again)

            {

            struct RandomSelection {
            public float probability;
                 List<int> scores = new List<int>();

                    Random generator = new Random();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)

                 {

                    int score = generator.Next(

                    new RandomSelction(-1, 0, .01f),

                    new RandomSelction(0, 1, .3f),

                    new RandomSelction(1, 2, .58f),

                    new RandomSelction(2, 3, .1f),

                    new RandomSelction(3, 4, .01f)

                    );
                }


            int GetRandomValue(params RandomSelection[] selections)
            {
                float rand = Random.value;
                float currentProb = 0;
                foreach (var selection in selections)
                {
                    currentProb += selection.probability;
                    if (rand <= currentProb)
                        return selection.GetValue();
                }
                Console.WriteLine(score);

                scores.Add(score);

            }



            ConsoleKeyInfo keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();

            Console.Clear();

            if (keyPressed.Key != ConsoleKey.Spacebar)

            {

                break;

            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: There's nothing specifically C# about this. If you were trying to map any uniform distribution to those numbers how would you do it? One way is to allocate each to part of the range 0-1, e.g. -1 = [0, 0.01), 0 = [0.01, 0.31), i.e. 0.3 on top of the 0.01 we have so far etc. And then you just have to take a random number in C# between 0 and 1 and work out which bucket it's in. Chances are you'd have to do it that way in any programming language that isn't maths focussed e.g. R or MatLab etc.

Comment: Yeah I did find out when I researched this that there wasn't a native function to do this in C#, I did attempt to use code I'd found online in order to seperate the selections after the generate.next() function to look something like this:

                    int score = generator.Next(

                    new RandomSelction(-1, 0, .01f),

                    new RandomSelction(0, 1, .3f),

                    new RandomSelction(1, 2, .58f),

                    new RandomSelction(2, 3, .1f),

                   new RandomSelction(3, 4, .01f)

But just overloaded the function

Comment: Actually if the distribution is fixed then since all your fractions are in hundreths you can just generate a random integer 0-99 and divide that into the right proportions -you can avoid using floats to keep it simple.

Comment: Yeah, I always want -1 to appear 10% of the time, 0 30% of the time etc so they are all fixed, so if I called the function 100 times it would pull them all based off of a fixed probabilitiy, I feel like my code is almost there I just dont actually know how to implement this, would you know any resources I could use to learn this? As I'm struggling to find a solution due to lack of experience with C# eventhough I know its definitely possible as other people have done similar things with their code

Comment: You should post your attempt to do this so people can help with wherever you're specifically stuck, rather than just asking "how can I do this".

Comment: you need to take all the talk of previous questions, that you are new, etc out of the question and make your questions very focused so they are easy to read and see what you are asking.

Comment: Perhaps this article will help: http://www.vcskicks.com/random-element.php

Comment: Forgive the many many ternaries but I can only post a comment now. This is the sort of thing I meant - hope it makes sense! `int percentage = generator.Next(100); int score = (percentage == 0) ? -1 : ((percentage <= 30) ? 0 : ((percentage <= 88) ? 1 : ((percentage <= 98) ? 2 : 3)));`

Comment: Thanks for the advice Rufus, I have added an edit with an attempt at some code that I made combining other solutions I had found online to the code presented in the original section of this post, I know its very messy and it doesnt work since I know I've failed to understand it in places as like I said I'm completely new to C# and and I'm just trying to understand how to get a function like this working, I hope this helps understand what I'm going for. Thanks

Comment: OP, the way to do this, typically, is to use the second option in the accepted answer to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150616/return-random-list-item-by-its-weight). The technique is language-neutral.